Registered Broadcast not being received by Android application when not in foreground (Java)
I'm developing an app for a local (tiny) firefighter station, because they don't have access to radios. I wanted to make an app that can act as an alarm button, that they can use instead of radios. (Currently they send SMS messages when theres a fire, but that is really slow to write and send). So I thought the app could write these messages automatically and send them out, and even "receive" alert messages and process them. For this I'm using a BroadcastReceiver that should be running indefinitely. The problem is that it only receives the messages when the application is open.
Note: Im using a Xiaomi Mi 11 for testing, I know that some manufacturers, including Xiaomi implemented a hell lot of restrictions regarding background processes. I turned off battery restrictions, "Pause app activity if unused" and every single disableable restriction I could find.
I read that since Android 7, receivers registered in the manifest don't always work, and most implicit receivers only work when the app is in the foreground (source). Luckily, I found that there are exceptions, and that Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION is one of them, as described here and here. However, it still does not work when the app is closed, such as swiped from recents or force stopped.
Manifest:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver"
android:enabled="true"
android:exported="true"
android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
    <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

SmsReceiver class:
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.provider.Telephony;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.Objects;

public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public SmsReceiver() {}

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.d("qvkrimp", "dbg1"); // line only prints when in foreground

        if (alertListener != null && Objects.equals(intent.getAction(), Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION)) {
            SmsMessage[] smsMessages = Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (SmsMessage message : smsMessages) {
                sb.append(message.getMessageBody());
            }

            String sender = smsMessages[0].getOriginatingAddress();
            String message = sb.toString();

            // message has to start with "[QVKR ALERT]"
            if (message.startsWith("[QVKR ALERT]")) {
                Log.d("qvkrimp", "dbg2");
            }
        }
    }
}

I have been reading relevant questions and documentations for the past 2 days, but I couldnt find a working one.
Did I do something wrong? Shouldn't the receiver work if it is described as an "exception"? Or is there a different approach to a reliable SMS receiver?
Thanks for any help!

Have you checked LogCat for any errors or informational logs that may indicate why the broadcast is not sent or is failing?

@dominicoder No errors or anything in the logcat regarding my app. Nothing about SMS or Telephony, and nothing after "Process Ended"

And just to be sure - you've cleared all filters from LogCat so you see everything? (it defaults to just your app / package, which would hide system logs)

Also - have you waited long enough? If your application has to be started to send the broadcast, that could take some time, definitely longer than if your app is active and in the foreground, so it might appear to not be working but actually just be slow.

@dominicoder I  read through all the logcat from the start of the process to the end and also after sending a message. I finally found something about "Unable to launch app for broadcast Intent". I searched google for the possible causes and turns out I have to ask for "autostart permission" first. I'll look into it. Thank you for the help


it still does not work when the app is...force stopped

Force stopping an app (as opposed to the process being killed to reclaim resources) prevents it from running until the user explicitly chooses otherwise.  This means that it won't get broadcasts until it's explicitly relaunched.
See, for example, this excerpt from the Android 15 behavior changes page (emphasis added):

The intention of the package FLAG_STOPPED state (which users can engage in AOSP builds by long-pressing an app icon and selecting "Force Stop") has always been to keep apps in this state until the user explicitly removes the app from this state by directly launching the app or indirectly interacting with the app (through the sharesheet or a widget, selecting the app as live wallpaper, etc.).


You mention that this also happens when the app is swiped away from recents.  That shouldn't happen, but I've heard anecdotes about some devices (I don't recall which ones) on which swiping apps away from recents triggers a force stop.  This is bad, for exactly this reason: it breaks apps by unregistering them from callbacks they are relying on getting.  It is possible that this is one such device.  To see if that's the issue, try another method of killing the app's process.

Well, I guess if someone really doesn't want the app to show alerts, they could use force stopping as a way to pause them (although there's a pause button in the app too). As for the "recents swipe", I solved it by requesting AutoStart permission on app launch.
Thanks a lot!
